# Getting random characters as output for c++ program in sublime text

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I am getting random characters as output.

[Screenshot of Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M11H.png)

Here is my sublime build code:

```
{
  "cmd" : ["g++ -std=c++14 $file_name -o $file_base_name && ./$file_base_name < inputf.in > outputf.in"], 
  "selector" : "source.c, source.c++",
  "shell": true,
  "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Can anyone help me out resolving this?

Comment: Those are not random values, but the hexadecimal forms of the characters in "Hello World".

Comment: Your program has output the text as expected you've just opened the text in a hex view

Comment: (OT: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h))

Answer (score 0):

Your program has written the hexadecimal ASCII codes of the string "Hello World!" into a binary file. That's why you are seeing the hexadecimal format in the editor.

For example, **48** for *'H'*, **65** for *'e'*, **6C** for *'l'*, etc.

Take a look at the [ASCII table](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue
Try using a new input and output file it will work fine.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35462606)